# Java Hangman game - replacing characters

Tags: java, replace

I am having problems with replacing the characters in the char array. I have tried the `.replace` method, but it does not seem to work. So do you know how to replace the letters in the char array, with the char variable `GuessedLetter`. This is code whole code I've developed so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hangman{

public static void main(String []args){
    Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] CollectionOfWords = {"apple","banana","pear","plum","watermelon"};

    int RadmNumber = (int) Math.ceil (Math.random() * CollectionOfWords.length);

    String RadmWord = CollectionOfWords[RadmNumber];

    System.out.println(RadmWord);
    char[] GenRadmLetter = RadmWord.toCharArray();
    char[] GenRadmLetter2 = RadmWord.toCharArray();
    for (int x = 0; x<GenRadmLetter.length; x++){
        GenRadmLetter[x]='?';
    }

    System.out.println(String.valueOf(GenRadmLetter));
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Hello. Guess a letter.");
    char GuessedLetter = Input.next().charAt(0);
    int RW = RadmWord.indexOf(GuessedLetter);
    String GenRadmLetterStr = String.valueOf(GenRadmLetter);

}

}
```

Thank you,

Comment: One advice, Java coding conventions recommend using lower letter as the first letter in variable names.

Comment: You will run into trouble with your way of randomly choosing a word. The chance for the first word in the collection to be chosen is almost zero. Math.random returns a double 0 <= x < 1 and Math.ceil will round it up to the next biggest integer in this case. So already a random value of 0.000001 would yield the second word, because Math.ceil(0.000001) == 1.0. Better remove the call to ceil and just cast to int, which cuts off the decimal places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to modify a `String`.

This class is immutable, so when you try something such as:

```
GenRadmLetter[x]='?';
```

You are not modifying the data inside the `RadmWord`.

What you could do, is something such as:

```
char[] GenRadmLetter2 = new char[RadmWord.length];
for (int x = 0; x < RadmWord.length; x++){
    GenRadmLetter[x]='?';
}
String result = new String(GenRadmLetter2);
```

Although, you may wish to keep the displayed `String` as a character array to allow easy changes to the display.

Comment: I'm thinking of replacing the position 'RW' of the 'GenRadmLetter' char array with the 'GuessedLetter' char variable. This is the code I though of so far: 'GenRadmLetter[RW] == GuessedLetter;', but I'm not sure about the correct way to write this code. Any tips? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3207654 the best way would be to iterate through the word the user is guessing and replace all occurrences in the string you are displaying (Filled with ?) at the given index.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, variable names should begin with a lowercase letter as such. A capital letter implies a class type. This is a very standard convention when it comes to Java, and as such it helps readability when sharing code with others.

```
String radmWord = collectionOfWords[radmNumber];
```

Secondly, the method `String.indexOf(Char)` only returns the first index of that character within the string. Since you would want to be replacing all occurrences of that character you would want to actually loop through the word checking each character to see if it is the character that was guessed. From there you could then replace that index within your guessing word. Take a look at this code I put together as an example, it should help you figure out what you need to do:

```
String randomWord = "apple";
String guessWord = "?????";
char guess = 'p';
for (int i = 0; i < randomWord.length(); i++) {
    if (randomWord.charAt(i) == guess) {
        char[] tempGuess = guessWord.toCharArray();
        tempGuess[i] = guess;
        guessWord = Arrays.toString(tempGuess);
    }
}
```